# Location of Maintenance Plan's Back Up Database Tasks information (SQL Server 2005)

Tags: sql-server-2005, maintenance

I would like to know where in the database or on the file system the information about Back Up Database Task in the Maintenance Plans Tasks.

I can find the Job in msdb.dbo.sysjobs
I can find the Subplan in msdb.dbo.sysmaintplan_subplans

But I need to find where and how the Task is being stored.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In SQL 2000 they were in the msdb database.

Specific table information can be found here:
http://www.toadworld.com/platforms/sql-server/w/wiki/9438.msdb-databases.aspx#Database_Maintenance_Plan_Tables

In SQL 2005 maintenance plans are modified SSIS (or DTS) packages and are stored in the dbo.sysdtspackages90 table.  (from: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic501078-5-1.aspx )

In SQL 2008 and 2012 they are in the [sysssispackages table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181582.aspx).

Comment: The sysdbmaintplan_... tables in msdb do not have any data in them. The sysdbmaintplans table has 1 record with a created date of 2005-10-14 (Long before this SQL server was installed.)

Comment: I have edited my answer with better information.