# Is it possible to retrieve the specific databases selected in a maintenance plan step?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, t-sql, maintenance

I would like to use a [tsql](/questions/tagged/tsql) query to retrieve the databases involved in one of the steps in a database backup plan I've created. From a [previous question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/2651/location-of-maintenance-plans-back-up-database-tasks-information-sql-server-20), I understand that somehow, the data is probably stored in the `msdb` database, but running a trace didn't reveal the query that retrieved the "checked" status of each selected database.

Does anyone know how SQL Server determines which of the server's databases are included in a particular job step?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe there is a way.  If you create a Maintenance Plan, it is going to be an SSIS package.  Querying the `msdb.dbo.sysjobsteps` table, you can view the actual `command`, but for an SSIS package execution it won't be indicative to the particulare databases you are backing up:

```
select
    step_name,
    subsystem,
    command
from msdb..sysjobsteps
```

This will give you something similar to the following command:

```
/Server "$(ESCAPE_NONE(SRVR))" /SQL "Maintenance Plans\MaintenancePlan" /set "\Package\BackupDBs.Disable;false"
```

Comment: Ah, OK, thanks. I'm not very familiar with SSIS, but I guess the next obvious question would be - any chance of using command line with SSIS to get the names (or is this more suitable for another question)?

Comment: @PeterMajeed Unfortunately, I don't think that's possible either.  See this reference (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162810%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) on the dtexec utility (used for SSIS execution from the command line).

Answer (score 2):

This will show the log history of any maintenance plan that includes the current database. It shows each step and if it succeeded. line3 contains string of DBs used for the given executions.

```
SELECT
    ld.server_name,
    mp.name AS [MTX Plan Name],
    msp.subplan_name AS [Sub Plan Name],    
    mpl.start_time AS [JobStart],
    mpl.end_time AS [JobEnd],
    mpl.succeeded AS [JobSucceeded],
    ld.start_time AS [StepStart],
    ld.end_time AS [StepEnd],
    ld.succeeded  AS [StepSucceeded],
    ld.line1,
    ld.line2,
    ld.line3,
    ld.line4,
    ld.line5,
    ld.command
FROM
    msdb.dbo.sysmaintplan_plans mp
    INNER JOIN msdb.dbo.sysmaintplan_subplans msp ON mp.id = msp.plan_id
    INNER JOIN msdb.dbo.sysmaintplan_log mpl ON msp.subplan_id = mpl.subplan_id
    INNER JOIN msdb.dbo.sysmaintplan_logdetail ld ON mpl.task_detail_id = ld.task_detail_id
        AND ld.command LIKE ('%['+db_name()+']%')
ORDER BY
    mpl.start_time DESC
```

Comment: will show the log history of any maintenance plan that includes the current database. It shows each step and if it succeeded.

line3 contains string of DBs used for the given executions

Answer (score 1):

Practically speaking, no, this is not possible.

Maintenance plans are stored as binary SSIS package images in `msdb.dbo.sysssispackages` and the image includes all the plan settings. In order to get the list of databases back, you would have to deserialize the raw package image somehow (undoubtedly fraught with peril... not recommended).